# VBA connect to SQL Server data source name not found and no default driver specified?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel, vba

I have the following VBA code and I am getting the error message stated in the title of this question. Can anybody please help? I don't usually write this sort of code:

```
Sub Save_To_DB()
'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "Server=server_name;Database=database_name;Trusted_Connection=True;"

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open **<-THE ERROR THROWS HERE**

'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Go on to write the SQL statement and execute
```

EDIT: Ok I solved it, needed to include `Driver={SQL Native Client};` in the connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that your connection string is wrong, look here for the right one http://www.connectionstrings.com/.

If you are having difficulties finding what will work for you, attach a table using the external data wizard and then look at the connection string that it provides:

```
CurrentDB.TableDefs("MyLinkedTable").Connect
```

Comment: Hi Remou, I used that website but there seems to be so many different ways of specifying it. Would you be able to give a small example of one you know works?

Comment: My connection string to SQL server is not going to work for you. You need to know things about your own server which it would not be a good idea to publish here. However, I will add a note to my answer.